# Get max value in third dimension from an array of shape (10, 21, 2) to get a final array of (10,21)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a state-value matrix as -

```
in[]: q

out[]: array([[[  1.78571429e-01,   4.00000000e-01],
    [  2.92307692e-01,   3.91304348e-01],
    [  3.93939394e-01,   4.21052632e-01],
    [  4.41176471e-01,   2.83916084e-01],
    [  1.48148148e-01,  -8.08080808e-02],
    [  4.08450704e-01,   2.94117647e-01],
    [  1.87500000e-01,   4.34782609e-02],
    [  3.05555556e-01,   4.60000000e-01],
    [  3.75000000e-01,  -6.66666667e-02],
    [  2.23880597e-01,   5.00000000e-01],
    [  2.41379310e-01,   5.00000000e-01],
    [  5.00000000e-01,  -6.66666667e-02],
    [  8.33333333e-02,   3.68421053e-01],
    [  5.00000000e-01,   1.80555556e-01],
    [  4.00000000e-01,   3.84615385e-01],
    [  2.94117647e-01,   2.13615023e-01],
    [  4.60000000e-01,   1.25000000e-01],
    [  7.46031746e-01,   3.58024691e-01],
    [  1.00000000e+00,   1.59420290e-01],
    [  1.00000000e+00,  -6.66666667e-02],
    [  0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00]],

   [[  4.68750000e-01,   1.48642430e-01],
    [  3.33333333e-02,   2.81004710e-01],
    [  6.25000000e-02,   2.09302326e-01],
    [  3.44262295e-01,   2.83582090e-01],
    [  3.60000000e-01,  -1.13235294e-01],
    [  2.94117647e-01,   3.51351351e-01],
    [  2.54237288e-01,   1.25000000e-01],
    [  1.90476190e-01,   7.50000000e-01],
    [  2.83018868e-01,   4.54545455e-01],
    [  2.09302326e-01,   4.25499232e-01],
    [  3.33333333e-01,   1.25000000e-01],
    [  4.16666667e-01,   3.66666667e-01],
    [  2.00000000e-01,   4.25499232e-01],
    [ -1.00000000e-01,   6.66666667e-02],
    [  5.23809524e-01,   6.00000000e-01],
    [  1.25000000e-01,  -6.97478992e-01],
    [  1.44444444e-01,   1.44444444e-01],
    [ -3.33333333e-01,   7.50000000e-01],
    [  1.00000000e+00,  -1.00000000e+00],
    [  1.00000000e+00,   4.54545455e-01],
    [  0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00]],

   [[  2.28070175e-01,   3.23076923e-01],
    [  3.23076923e-01,   2.61538462e-01],
    [  3.75000000e-01,   2.09176788e-01],
    [  6.12244898e-02,   3.33333333e-01],
    [  2.32876712e-01,   2.25464191e-01],
    [  2.42424242e-01,   8.04597701e-02],
    [  2.64705882e-01,   1.91394777e-01],
    [  2.25806452e-01,   2.09176788e-01],
    [  4.76923077e-01,   5.55555556e-02],
    [  8.88888889e-02,   1.42857143e-01],
    [  2.41379310e-01,   2.06171108e-01],
    [  3.33333333e-01,   1.00000000e+00],
    [  2.30769231e-01,   2.00000000e-01],
    [  2.72727273e-01,   4.08163265e-02],
    [  2.00000000e-01,   2.22079589e-01],
    [ -6.66666667e-02,   2.22079589e-01],
    [  5.55555556e-02,  -1.00000000e+00],
    [  6.66666667e-01,   4.08163265e-02],
    [  6.36363636e-01,  -9.09090909e-02],
    [  1.00000000e+00,   2.14285714e-01],
    [  0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00]],

   [[  2.18750000e-01,   7.14285714e-02],
    [  5.26315789e-02,   2.13921902e-01],
    [  2.00000000e-01,   2.08888889e-01],
    [ -1.61290323e-01,   9.72222222e-01],
    [ -1.01449275e-01,   1.70568562e-01],
    [  1.27272727e-01,   1.04370891e-01],
    [  2.46753247e-01,   8.33333333e-02],
    [  2.35294118e-01,   1.66666667e-01],
    [  2.77777778e-02,   2.30769231e-01],
    [ -9.67741935e-02,   2.30769231e-01],
    [  3.57142857e-01,  -1.52941176e-01],
    [  2.38095238e-01,  -9.09090909e-02],
    [  2.63157895e-01,   1.81818182e-01],
    [  8.33333333e-02,   1.00000000e+00],
    [ -4.76190476e-02,  -1.11111111e-01],
    [  2.30769231e-01,   1.81818182e-01],
    [ -1.52941176e-01,   1.30434783e-01],
    [  6.92307692e-01,   2.50000000e-01],
    [  6.66666667e-01,  -1.11111111e-01],
    [  1.00000000e+00,   1.31313131e-01],
    [  0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00]],

   [[  1.60000000e-01,   1.64179104e-01],
    [ -3.22580645e-02,   1.49253731e-02],
    [  4.11764706e-01,   2.54237288e-01],
    [ -1.44927536e-02,   1.30434783e-01],
    [  1.00000000e-01,  -5.08474576e-02],
    [  1.50684932e-01,  -1.42857143e-01],
    [ -7.93650794e-02,   1.50684932e-01],
    [  2.66666667e-01,   1.66666667e-01],
    [  1.66666667e-01,  -4.54545455e-02],
    [  1.42857143e-01,  -4.54545455e-02],
    [  1.30434783e-01,   1.81818182e-01],
    [  5.88235294e-02,   1.66666667e-01],
    [ -9.09090909e-02,   1.53846154e-01],
    [  2.50000000e-01,  -1.42857143e-01],
    [ -7.69230769e-02,   1.50684932e-01],
    [  1.76470588e-01,  -2.65432099e-01],
    [  2.50000000e-01,  -4.54545455e-02],
    [  1.37500000e-01,   2.41379310e-01],
    [  1.00000000e+00,   1.81818182e-01],
    [  6.00000000e-01,   1.81818182e-01],
    [  0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00]],

   [[ -6.06060606e-02,  -1.85185185e-01],
    [  1.66666667e-01,  -5.26315789e-02],
    [  1.86440678e-01,   3.44827586e-02],
    [ -1.61290323e-01,   3.91304348e-01],
    [  3.84615385e-02,   2.00000000e-01],
    [ -9.80392157e-02,   1.80645161e-01],
    [  1.11111111e-01,  -1.61290323e-01],
    [  1.52542373e-01,   8.18181818e-01],
    [  2.94117647e-02,   5.29411765e-01],
    [  1.03448276e-01,  -9.80392157e-02],
    [  3.91304348e-01,   8.00000000e-01],
    [ -2.77555756e-17,  -1.00000000e+00],
    [  3.44827586e-02,  -1.05820106e-01],
    [  2.00000000e-01,  -4.34782609e-02],
    [  5.29411765e-01,   8.18181818e-01],
    [  2.72727273e-01,   4.97737557e-02],
    [  1.11111111e-01,  -1.86440678e-01],
    [  6.14035088e-01,  -1.05820106e-01],
    [  8.18181818e-01,  -3.70370370e-02],
    [  1.00000000e+00,  -1.00000000e+00],
    [  0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00]],

   [[ -1.22807018e-01,   7.24637681e-02],
    [ -7.93650794e-02,   1.21212121e-01],
    [ -7.69230769e-02,   6.66666667e-01],
    [  1.34328358e-01,   2.05479452e-01],
    [  7.24637681e-02,   1.00000000e-01],
    [ -1.42857143e-01,  -2.14285714e-01],
    [  2.28070175e-01,   4.76190476e-02],
    [  4.76190476e-02,   5.56708673e-01],
    [  1.66666667e-01,  -2.14285714e-01],
    [ -2.11267606e-01,   5.05912620e-01],
    [  1.00000000e-01,   5.68627451e-01],
    [  2.50000000e-01,   1.00000000e+00],
    [ -3.33333333e-01,   5.56708673e-01],
    [ -3.04347826e-01,   5.64705882e-01],
    [  0.00000000e+00,  -5.15570934e-01],
    [  1.66666667e-01,   0.00000000e+00],
    [  5.05912620e-01,   5.68627451e-01],
    [  5.78947368e-01,   5.05912620e-01],
    [  1.00000000e+00,   7.86599022e-02],
    [  1.00000000e+00,  -5.42483660e-01],
    [  0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00]],

   [[ -1.91489362e-01,  -2.90322581e-01],
    [ -2.04081633e-02,  -1.32231405e-01],
    [ -4.10958904e-02,  -6.56790123e-02],
    [ -2.92307692e-01,  -5.67733990e-01],
    [ -3.12500000e-02,  -2.94117647e-01],
    [ -2.90322581e-01,  -2.25806452e-01],
    [ -4.54545455e-01,  -5.26315789e-02],
    [ -1.29032258e-01,  -1.52542373e-01],
    [ -7.50000000e-02,  -9.23629929e-02],
    [ -7.46268657e-02,  -2.91666667e-01],
    [ -2.25806452e-01,  -1.52542373e-01],
    [ -2.94117647e-01,  -2.91666667e-01],
    [  5.88235294e-02,  -1.97090909e-01],
    [  5.88235294e-02,  -5.67733990e-01],
    [ -1.42857143e-01,  -1.63636364e-01],
    [ -5.26315789e-02,  -4.73170732e-01],
    [ -2.91666667e-01,  -1.57894737e-01],
    [ -2.50000000e-01,   8.18181818e-01],
    [  1.00000000e+00,  -5.34482759e-01],
    [  1.00000000e+00,  -1.00000000e+00],
    [  0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00]],

   [[  8.77192982e-02,  -3.63636364e-01],
    [  1.42857143e-01,  -5.71428571e-02],
    [ -5.71428571e-02,  -1.72167707e-01],
    [ -3.33333333e-01,  -7.24637681e-02],
    [ -3.23076923e-01,  -2.00595238e-01],
    [ -2.18750000e-01,  -8.33333333e-02],
    [ -2.50000000e-01,   1.11111111e-01],
    [ -3.51351351e-01,  -7.24637681e-02],
    [ -2.20338983e-01,  -2.00595238e-01],
    [ -3.23529412e-01,   1.06227106e-01],
    [ -1.20000000e-01,  -1.87500000e-01],
    [ -5.20000000e-01,  -1.42857143e-01],
    [ -4.54545455e-01,  -2.00595238e-01],
    [ -1.42857143e-01,   1.06227106e-01],
    [ -1.42857143e-01,  -2.00595238e-01],
    [  1.11111111e-01,   1.98412698e-01],
    [ -1.17647059e-01,   1.06227106e-01],
    [  1.06227106e-01,  -4.00000000e-01],
    [  8.57142857e-01,  -1.87500000e-01],
    [  6.92307692e-01,  -1.11111111e-01],
    [  0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00]],

   [[ -6.12244898e-02,  -3.06122449e-01],
    [ -3.33333333e-01,  -2.72727273e-01],
    [ -2.78688525e-01,  -3.23936961e-01],
    [ -9.43396226e-02,  -3.20000000e-01],
    [  6.06060606e-02,  -2.80000000e-01],
    [ -2.69841270e-01,  -2.38095238e-01],
    [ -3.20000000e-01,  -3.20000000e-01],
    [ -2.00000000e-01,   1.40000000e-01],
    [ -3.82352941e-01,   2.26190476e-01],
    [ -2.63157895e-01,  -2.98245614e-01],
    [ -2.72727273e-01,   1.40000000e-01],
    [ -3.68421053e-01,   1.40000000e-01],
    [ -3.00000000e-01,  -1.09230324e-02],
    [ -3.75000000e-01,   1.40000000e-01],
    [ -2.00000000e-01,   2.77555756e-17],
    [  2.00000000e-01,  -5.86428571e-01],
    [  2.95138889e-02,  -3.26923077e-01],
    [  2.26190476e-01,   2.26190476e-01],
    [  5.00000000e-02,   3.33333333e-01],
    [  5.00000000e-01,  -2.18750000e-01],
    [  0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00]]])
```

I want to find max of corresponding values from q[:,:,0] and q[:,:,1] to obtain a resulting matrix of shape (10, 21)

Comment: `np.max(d, axis=2)` ?

Comment: To know more about how to perform such operations, please visit [`NumPy ufuncs`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `numpy.amax`, it returns the maximum of an array or maximum along an axis.

Example (your case):

In: `np.amax(np.array([[[1,2],[5,6]],[[10,11],[15,16]]]), 2)`

Out: 
`array([[ 2,  6], [11, 16]])`